# u-blox M8N doesn't save Baudrate and no fw update possible

Tags: module, gps, updates, firmware, baud-rate

yesterday I got my "Ublox M8N Module". I bought it at ebay.

I connected it with Arduino Uno as USB to Serial Bridge.

I can change Baud rate to 115'200, disconnect in Ucenter and connect with 115'200. If I unplug the module from USB, the config is lost. Baud rate is 9'600 again. If I try to Update from 2.01 to 3.01 it doesn't work.

Battery Voltage is at 2.5V and it finds lots of fixes just in seconds.

Do you have any idea whats going wrong? How can I find out, if its a fake and what I have to do to make a fw update.

Here is the log from the fw updater:

```
Starting Flash Firmware Update
Loading and checking firmware image
Load FW binary 'C:\Users\User\Documents\GPS\M8N Firmware\UBX_M8_301_SPG.911f2b77b649eb90f4be14ce56717b49.bin'
Binary check success, G80 image valid.
Version: 3.01 (107900)
FLASH Base:          0x800000
FW Base:             0x800000
FW Start:            0x86C16D
FW End:              0x8808CC
FW Size:             0x808D4
Transfer Packetsize: 512
Transfer Packets:    1029
Checking communication link...
Communication link OK.
Identifying receiver updater version at 9600 baud.
Firmware loader version 5.01 detected.
Suitable Multi-ROM image found
Check pass: u-blox8 Multi-ROM image -> u-blox8 ROM2.01-receiver
Identifying Flash
Flash Detection timed out.
Done in 10.1 sec.
Statistics:
    Erases sent:    0
    Writes sent:    0
    Erase timeouts: 0
    Write timeouts: 0
```

This is the module:

http://abload.de/image.php?img=img_20170319_122602ccum3.jpg

Here is a Screenshot from the messages box:

http://abload.de/image.php?img=screenshotqhuli.png

Comment: Could you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same mudule fron China. It's fake.
It's a module with a rom, not a flashram.
They put a new sticker on the module.
So, it's not possible to change settings.